# Google Calendar Invite via Wordpress Email Form Submission

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api, contact-form-7

This is more of a simple yes or no question with the hope that someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm currently working on a Wordpress-based website for a school which allows users to fill out a contact form (Contact Form 7), and select a date to make an appointment with the principal of the school. This form submission then needs to create the standard Google Calendar invite for the principal to accept.

Basically, the question is, is it possible to create a Google Calendar Event/Invite via a form submission from a website?

Much appreciated.

Comment: where you able to make this work?? please if so, share your approach !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is possible but, I'm not sure if you can do it using contact-form-7 since I'm not familiar with it. So the alternative way is to use Google Appscript and Google Forms.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.jessespevack.com/systems-leadership/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event) to know how to implement this.

Here's a snippet:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {

  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      length = responses.length,
      lastResponse = responses[length-1],
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses(),
      eventObject = {};
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();

    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
    } 
  }
  return eventObject;
}
```